# Vertical spacing in headline is off

Tags: fonts, vertical-alignment, fontsize

In my bachelors thesis I have a problem with the title.
The vertical spacing between the lines in the title seems a bit off and looks like this:

[image]

It seems to me that the space between the first and second line is normal, whereas the space between line 2 and line 3 is too tight.

Since I am using a template provided by my universtiy and I have no idea why this is happening it is a bit hard for me to figure out a fix, thats why I am asking this question.

The code looks like this:

```
\thesistitle{Entwicklung und empirische Überprüfung einer Software zur Detektion von Fake-Profilen in Social Discovery Applikationen}

\begin{minipage}[t][2.8cm][t]{\textwidth}%
\begin{center}
{\thesistitlefontHUGE\sffamily\bfseries\tuinfthesistitle}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}

\newcommand{\thesistitlefontHUGE}{\fontsize{22}{25}\selectfont}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Remove the `{}` inside the `center` environment.

Comment: Alternatively, add `\par` before the closing brace.

Comment: the line spacing is set for the whole paragraph at the end of the paragraph, so you have HUGE text squeezed into \normalsize line spacing as the font size reverts at the `}` before the paragraph ends.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So line spacing is correct for the first lines but not the last.

Comment: @ChristophFrings No it is wrong for them all. the same baselineskip is used for the whole paragraph.  But as the specified spacing is less than the size of the characters tex gives up on even spacing and each row just takes up as much space as it needs separated by \lineskip (1pt) so lines that happen to have a capital or a descender such as `g` take up more space than a line that happens to have all lower case.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK! (and thx for understanding my comment was a question, despite me forgetting the correct mark...)